# When an application cluster in one data center fails over to a different data center, what happens with the connected Redis machines?

Tags: redis, high-availability, failover

// , THEY EXPLODE.

Seriously, though, it looks like [Sentinel](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel) handles the actual failover if a Redis cluster deactivates. However, let's assume that no Redes* die, and that both datacenters have Redis clusters for the application.

Do the Redis clusters "nearer" the newly active application cluster start gradually taking over its traffic or caching?

*I took Latin when I was young. The internet says that "-es" declines nouns that end in "-is" to make them plural.

Answer (score 0):

That only applies to Latin roots and works. ;)

That aside the arrangement you list is not simple, even if configured "correctly". That would mean having sentinels in each data center, but to do that you can't split them 50/50 or you will get split-brain if a DC loses connectivity to the other.

This you have to either pick a third DC to run sentinels in, splitting them three ways and keeping a majority for quorum. In this way you can reduce the risk by requiring two DCs to decide in a failover.

However, if it is only networking the original master DC's local clients will still be connected to the local master, and you could still have split brain. If you are taking from this that running a pod (please do not call a non-cluster a cluster it only makes things confusing) across multiple data centers is tricky and fraught with peril, you would be correct.

In order to minimize this risk you could run non-promotable slaves in the secondary data center and only issue reads to them from that DC and route writes to the master in the primary DC. This also means not letting sentinel failover to the secondary, but doing it manually if it is called for.

Neither sentinel nor redis are designed for cross-datacenter replication and failover. You will need to design and write a system to handle it for you in a way that works for your application. I advise great care in such a system.